# Pandas : How to round off to the value in conditional and desired way in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
data = {'period':[.253, .503, .750, 1.000 1.023, 1.300, 2.00, 2.012, 2.123, 3.000, 3.034, 4.000, 4.054, 4.250], 'd_rate':[1.02, 1.52, 2.34, 'Null', 8.58, 2.97, 'Null', 5.54, 7.89, 'Null', 6.64, 'Null', 7.32, 5.34],'c_rate':[2.84, 3.12, 4.56, 6.10, 'Null', 1.34, 3.65, 'Null', 5.87, 8.43, 'Null', 3.89, 'Null', 7.01]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to consider the values which are more than 1 in `'period'` column. I would like to round off the `'period'` column in conditional way. Example : `1.023`to `1.000`, `2.012` to `2.000`, `3.034` to `3.000`, `4.054` to `4.000`...But the values like `1.300, 2.123, 4.250, etc` remain the same. It means if the value is after decimal starts will `0` then it should round off to complete number. And the corresponding values in `'d_rate'` must be aligned with the complete number after rounding off. Please suggest.
My expected df output should be as below :

```
period d_rate c_rate
0.253   1.02   2.84
0.503   1.52   3.12
0.750   2.34   4.56
1.000   8.58    6.1
1.023   Null   Null
1.300   2.97   1.34
2.000   5.54   3.65
2.012   Null   Null
2.123   7.89   5.87
3.000   6.64   8.43
3.034   Null   Null
4.000   7.32   3.89
4.054   Null   Null
4.250   5.34   7.01
```

Comment: Never use string values in float column like 'Null'. Use standard notation `np.nan`.

Comment: This is not a coding service.  Please post your attempt.  You're trying to identify values whose fractional part is less than 0.1 -- write a filter for that.

Comment: Your input and expected output is exactly the same. It would be clearer if you could provide your input too, as your explanation is not fully rule-based.

Comment: @ycx..Please see the input and output. Both are different. check column d_rate.

Comment: @Prune ..am not expecting code either. Please dont judge. Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Then you need to be clear about your problem (your input is not in an easily read form, hard to compare with the output) and what you expect.  "Please suggest" is not a specification, and is too broad for Stack Overflow.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour.

Answer (score 1):

To me it is not really clear. It looks like your question is about how to apply formatting to a specific dataframe column. You can do for example:

```
import numpy as np
def formatter(x):
    if np.greater(x,1):
        return round(x,2)
    else:
        return round(x,1)

df['period'] = df['period'].apply(lambda x: formatter(x))
```

This is a general example of defining a formatting function, please make it to your case applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to conditionally round to floor if the decimal is less than 0.1 (i.e. 0.07, 0.09, 0.01 etc.)

Perhaps this would solve your problem

```
from math import modf
import numpy as np

to_round = data['period']
rounded = [np.floor(tor) if modf(tor)[0]<0.1 for tor in to_round]
data[<mynewcolumn>] = rounded
```