# Reduce decimals shown for large numbers but not for small

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, number-formatting

When formatting floats, is there any python method/formatting for reducing how many decimals that is shown as the number becomes larger?

It could for instance be a limit to how many digits of the number that is shown. Example below:

```
 100.145 ->  100
   2.392 ->    2.39
  34.827 ->   34.8
4599.298 -> 4599
```

Comment: My first thought is using an if statement to achieve it. You can set the limit manually for the limit there. (When I'm at my pc I can provide a more detailed answer, but maybe this is already helpful) Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I was actually hoping there was already a wheel, so I don't have to invent it myself.

Comment: True, that's understandable, but it's kinda specific what you want to do. But maybe this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61184313/7775043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

As chux points out in his comment, my original solution does not work for
boundary cases in which rounding leads to a carry. Also, I didn't pay attention
to the fact that `log10(100) == 2 != 3`.
The second bug is easy to come by. To fix the first one, I came up with a
recursion. Now it should work but isn't simple anymore.

```
import math

def flexible_format(num_in, total_digits):
    try:
        digits_before_decimal = math.floor(math.log10(abs(num_in))) + 1
    except ValueError:
        # if num == 0
        return '0'
    digits_after_decimal = max(0, total_digits - digits_before_decimal)
    # if rounding increases number of digits, we have to format once again
    # after that, an additional rounding doesn't increase the number of digits
    # so we can be sure not to land in an infinite recursion 
    num_out = round(num_in, digits_after_decimal)
    if math.floor(math.log10(abs(num_out))) >= digits_before_decimal:
        return flexible_format(num_out, total_digits)
    return f'{num_out:.{digits_after_decimal}f}'

list_nums =  [-100.145,  2.392, -34.827 , 4599.298, 99.95, 100 ]
for num in list_nums:
    print(flexible_format(num, total_digits=3))
 
# -100
# 2.39
# -34.8
# 4599
# 100
# 100
```

**Original false solution:**

I don't know a commonly used function achieving that, but it is easy to implement.

```
import math

def flexible_format(num, total_digits):
    try:
        digits_before_decimal = math.ceil(math.log10(abs(num)))
    except ValueError:
        # if num == 0
        return '0'
    digits_after_decimal = max(0, total_digits - digits_before_decimal)
    return f'{num:.{digits_after_decimal}f}'

list_nums =  [-100.145,  2.392, -34.827 , 4599.298, 0]

for num in list_nums:
    print(flexible_format(num, total_digits=3))

# -100
# 2.39
# -34.8
# 4599
# 0
```

Comment: Edge cases are a concern.  Try values that round in printing to more digits like 99.51 to "100.00" yet `math.log10(abs(num)` is not `log10(100.00)`.  Note fails for 0.0 due to `log10(0)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Valid point! Although 99.51 doesn't break my original function 
(for total_digits=3), 99.95 does.  I fixed that, but now the solution feels less satisfying.

Comment: Other edge cases that may merit review such as `nextafter(99.95,100)` and `nextafter(99.95,0)`.  I am not well versed  enough in Python, but well versed in FP.  Good luck.